JPQL Query With Map Key and Value For Json Field
I have an Entity like:
class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "fields")
    private Map<String, Object> fields;
}

And I try to write a query like:
@Query("""
        select case count(1) from MyEntity i
        where i.fields[:fieldKey] = :fieldValue
        """)
Long existsByFieldValue(@Param("fieldKey") String fieldKey, @Param("fieldValue") Object fieldValue);

Is there a way to handle it on JPQL/HQL?
Note: Also tried KEY() VALUE() functions but they works only for table-relations.
